# Trying to remove the padding from the navigation menu so the colors don't change when hovering

Tags: html, css, wordpress, button, padding

The theme we purchased allows you to choose primary and secondary colors, but I want the color to be different when hovering over the main navigation menu. I am not sure how to remove this "child" from the navigation menu only. I tried removing the padding which worked, but then the alignment was off. The items should be blue when hovered, not yellow and then blue. Website is: http://www.stephensengineering.com/stephens33/ .

```
/*         Home  Navigation    */

.nav-t-holder {
    position: relative;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-header {
    display: none;
    padding: 12px 20px;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-header button {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer {
    display: block;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1.6em 0;
    position: relative;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li:hover a,
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li.active a {
    color: #0071bd;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li:last-child > a {
    border: none;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li:first-child > a
{
    padding: 0 1.3em 0 0;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li > a {
    padding: 0 1.3em;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-right: 1px dashed #3f5262;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li > ul.sub-menu {
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li > ul.sub-menu.align-right {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li:hover > ul.sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display:block;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li > ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li > ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu.align-right {
    right: 100%;
    left: auto;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li > ul.sub-menu > li:hover > ul.sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 275px;
    opacity: 0;
    display:none;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 99999;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    padding-left: 0;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li ul.sub-menu li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li ul.sub-menu li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li ul.sub-menu li:last-child a:after {
    display: none;
}
nav.main_menu .nav-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li ul.sub-menu li:hover > a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #51c5e9;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li > ul.sub-menu > li:hover > ul.sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display:block;
}
nav.main_menu .nav-holder ul.nav.ind-menu li.current-menu-item a{
    color: #fab90a;
}

nav.main_menu .nav-holder ul.nav.ind-menu li ul.sub-menu li.current-menu-item a,nav.main_menu .nav-holder ul.nav.ind-menu li ul.sub-menu li.current-menu-item a:active  {
    color: #ffffff!important;
    background: #51c5e9;
}
nav.main_menu .nav-holder ul.nav.ind-menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
    color: #242424;
    font: 600 16px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 15px 25px 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 600;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav.main_menu .nav-holder ul.nav.ind-menu li ul.sub-menu li:last-child a{
    border-bottom: none;
}
.nav-t-holder ul.nav li.has-t-sub-menu > a > button {
    display: none;
}
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-header {
    display: none;
    padding: 12px 0px;
    float: right;
}
.touch_top ul .item .media .blue-color a i {
    color: #1fa6c8;
}
```

Comment: Still no luck. :(

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have a color(yellow) being assigned to the anchor when the parent `li` is being hovered, as well as a color(blue) being assigned to the anchor when the anchor itself is being hovered. If you want it to be blue when the parent `li` is being hovered, change it to this:

```
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li:hover a, .nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav li.active a, .service-info a h4:hover, .nav-holder .nav-footer ul.nav > li:hover a, .nav-holder .nav-footer ul.nav > li.active a, .our-sol-wrapper p span, .single-blog-post .meta-info .content-box .post-links li i, .team .box-img .caption a {
    color: #0071bd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two conflicting hover events. Hovering over the `<li>` sets the link to be yellow. Hovering over the `<a>` directly sets the link to be blue.

```css
// The culprit for the yellow colour
.nav-t-holder .nav-t-footer ul.nav > li:hover a{
    color: #ffba00;
}

// For the blue colour
nav.main_menu .nav-holder ul.nav.ind-menu li{
    color: #0071bd;
}
```

You can change the rules of the `<a>` hover to set the color to be `initial`, which will effectively stop the hover changing color.

```css
// Use initial to stop it interfering
nav.main_menu .nav-holder ul.nav.ind-menu li{
    color: initial;
}
```

Or failing that, just set both to change it to yellow.